# Custom domain on GitHub Pages not working properly

Tags: github, dns, github-pages, cname, namecheap

I purchased a domain on NameCheap, and followed a step-by-step guide to configure it with GitHub Pages (I'm pretty new to all of this).

But my GitHub page is not using the custom domain even after configured

The first step was to configure the 4 A records and the CNAME with my username in github:
[image: Advanced DNS]

After that I went to the repository that has my username and set up GitHub Pages, and then added my custom domain:
[image: GitHub Pages]

So far, everything worked perfectly, he re-deployed and added a CNAME file to the master branch

But when I try to use GitHub Pages in other repositories, it still gets the old domain (username.github.io)
[image: Old domain name]

What I really wanted was for this project to be in custom.domain/project-name

Any light on what I'm doing wrong?

I didn't find anything different from what I did looking at the official documentation

**Of course I didn't use these names from the images, I just removed the original name.